# Making a Godot game window non-interactive

Tags: gdscript

I’m working on a game using the **Godot engine**. I’m using a transparent background for the window, and I want only the UI to be visible. However, I want the window to be non-interactive, so that the user can interact with elements outside the window, even when the game is active.

I’ve tried using a transparent background and making **the window non-interactive,** but I couldn’t find a way to achieve this in Godot. Is there a way to achieve this in Godot, or are there any alternative solutions I could use?

*Any help would be appreciated.*

What did you try? You could describe the steps you took in Godot to make the game window non-interactive. For example, “I tried setting the window to be transparent and full screen in the Godot settings. I also attempted to disable mouse and keyboard input in the game window.”

What were you expecting? You could explain what you thought would happen after your attempts. For example, “I expected that the game window would become non-interactive, allowing the user to interact with elements outside the game window even when the game is active.”